# Best and efficient way to mask a dynamic url

Tags: java, url, logging, masking

I am working on a project where we call an API via a url which has two parts: Fixed + variable.
So for example the url is: [www.example.com/this](http://www.example.com/this)
This url is appended with a number/string and becomes: [www.example.com/this/123456](http://www.example.com/this/123456)

We call this url from our code and log this into the logger. But what I need that the logger should log this url as [www.example.com/this/XXXXXX](http://www.example.com/this/XXXXXX) and not the complete url.

Can someone tell me the most efficient way to do this as I don't want to make it complex to log just into the logger.

Answer (score 0):

Mask the URL using regex:

```
String logUrl = url.replaceAll("\\w+$", "");
```

This deletes all letters/numbers from the end of the string.